# What is the translation of "indoors" and "outdoors"?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Esktere* is often used in sentences like *La infanoj ludas ekstere.* What is the word for *indoors*? I've considered *endome*.

Is that the correct word, or are there better ones?

Answer (score 9):

"*Endome*" is a fine choice.  Several dictionaries agree on it as a translation for "indoors".  However, it specifically means "in the house".  If they were in a school or some other building, I'd be inclined to use something more general like "*ene*" or "*interne*".